# Get stores id of static block on Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, static-block, store-id

For programatically create a static block I use a function that behaves like this pieces of code

```
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
    $block->setTitle($title);
    $block->setIdentifier($identifier);
    $block->setStores(array($storeId));
    $block->setIsActive($isActive);
    $block->setContent($content);
    $block->save();
```

But if I want to know the stores of a static block what I want to do.
I try innocently to call `getStores` on block but this not works

```
    $blockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
    foreach($blockCollection as $block) {
        var_dump($block->getIdentifier());
        var_dump($block->getStores());
    }
```

there is something wrong that I forget ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stores are stored in a different table `cms_block_store`.

To lookup the store ids you can do the following:

```
$blockCollection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
foreach($blockCollection as $block) {
    $storeIds = $block->getResource()->lookupStoreIds($block->getBlockId());
}
```